# How to convert Python OpenCV Image Matrix into a List of 4x4 blocks

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an image in the form of a matrix of 512 x 512 entries. Something like

```
[[12,234, . . ... .  (512 entries)],
 [[12,234, . . ... .  (512 entries)],
 [[12,234, . . ... .  (512 entries)],
 .
 .
 [12,234, . . ... .  (512 entries)]]
```

I want to break the image into 4x4 blocks and put them into one list. How do I do this? There would be 128 blocks of size 4 x 4, starting indexing from left.

Comment: So, there would be `128 x 128` blocks right?

Comment: How would you do it?

Comment: I think I would just pass.

Comment: `You’re only as good as your weakest link`

Comment: `image[0:4, 0:4]`, etc. `image[a*4:a*4+4, b*4:b*4+4]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OpenCV` use `numpy` and `numpy` lets you use indexes like `image[0:4, 0:4]` to get square:

So you need something similar to this:

```
width, height = image.shape

# for image with ie. `RGB` color (3 bytes in every pixel)
#width, height, depth = image.shape 

blocks = []

for y in range(0, height, 4):
    for x in range(0, width, 4):
        blocks.append(image[y:y+4, x:x+4])
```

Comment: `ValueError: need more than 2 values to unpack
`

Comment: Thanks furas you are the real god, unlike the fakester @Divakar

Comment: @Solly you are right - I tested on real image with `RGB` color.

Comment: yes. You are the boss. This is a great solution. Poles rockk

Answer (score 2):

Here is a function I use for this purpose:

```
def blockshaped(arr, nrows, ncols):

   h, w = arr.shape
   return (arr.reshape(h//nrows, nrows, -1, ncols)
           .swapaxes(1,2)
           .reshape(-1, nrows, ncols))
```

Where:
arr = your input 2D np array

windowsize = integer, representing the size of the tiles

The output is an array of shape (n, nrows, ncols) where n * nrows * ncols = arr.size.

Comment: Dude that is wayy to long. Furas is way more shorter

Comment: Its longer code, but much faster because there are no for-loops. If you need to process a large amount of images you do not want to use for-loop with Numpy

Comment: Thats good info @cf2. Would you be able to mod this code to store the results as a pair of blocks? I mean, in the final list, you store the values as tuples where each tuple is (block, block_no) where block_no is the order this block is processed in?